# What is an efficient way of using large set of locations details in an application

Tags: php, android, ios, json, google-maps

I'm trying to improve my app performance. I have an SQL + Php server with ~ 25k markers. The website run on wordpress so they are stored as Posts object in a table with ID and title and the other details (latitude, longitude, description, ratings, type, elements,..10+ other informations) are stored in another post_meta table.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to display those markers on android/iOS maps. The current implementation is that when the user click a button or move to much and stop on the map, it make a request to my php server with the bounding box of the screen, who retrieve the informations on my database and send back a json file.
If i want the user to not wait for the markers to display and to have a good user experience, i have some limitation. I need to block the zoom of the user so it will not have a too large bouding box and not retrieve too many markers or i have to limit the number of informations i return with the request (only title and lat/lng).

But then if i want to have some client side filters option on the map (like the type, average rating, elements, picture or not, ...) i cannot retrieve only title and lat/lng or i would have to remake a request each time the user select/unselect a filter... I would like to have filters on the client side.

I'm not displaying any informations about the marker except is latitude/longitude on the map unless he click on a marker, then i would load a sheet view with all the details.

I do not have the science nor the server equipment to perform large server side clustering like google or similar application do but i still want my user to have a good experience on their mobile.

One solution i have think off would be to make two request, one for title + lat/lng and one that fit my filters option. The user will quickly see all the markers on the map but will have to wait some seconds to use the filters ?

Do you think i should stick to my limitation (server side filters or return all the data but block the user to a max zoom + limit number of markers to retrieve) ? Or do you suggest other suggestions that my monkey brain (and the two brain of my colleagues) hasn't tought of ?

If you need more explanation or some example, key performances feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the zoom levels on a map, you can use this code:

```
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(
  withLatitude: 41.887,
  longitude: -87.622,
  zoom: 12
)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
mapView.setMinZoom(10, maxZoom: 15)
```

In your API, you could have either a bounding box, or a centre Latitude & Longitude with a zoom parameter.